# Package does not exist when importing JAR file

Tags: java, netbeans, import, jar, package

I have a JAR file that contains a series of .java files/stub code. I need to include the JAR into a NetBeans project and call the various methods contained within.  I've attempted Solaris as well, but no luck there either.

At the moment, the entirety of my Main.java (the only src file in the project) is:

```
package TestApplication;

import edu.university.department.ws.DiscoveryServices;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World");
    }
}
```

The exact error is:

```
C:\code\Projects\WebServiceTest\TestApplication\src\testapplication\Main.java:3: package edu.university.department.ws does not exist
import edu.university.department.ws.DiscoveryServices;
1 error
```

I added the JAR file by going to libraries, clicking Add JAR/Folder, and selecting the JAR. Once it was added, I can drill down into it in NetBeans and see all the stub code, including edu.university.department.ws.DiscoveryServices.java, but yet it can't seem to import it.

I also tried going to Tools -> Libraries then adding the JAR to the classpath there. It didn't change anything.

Is it possible the JAR file wasn't created correctly?  I can see the code in NetBeans, so I don't think anything is wrong with the JAR, but I'm new at this and not sure what I should be looking for.

Thanks!

Comment: You should open your project Properties and add the library to wich you added the jar in your project

Comment: What's the name of the jar file?

Comment: As I mentioned, I added the JAR file through the Properties -> Library -> Add Jar functionality.  The JAR is not a standard library.

Comment: Wrong JAR file. They've given you the source code. Maybe they intend you to compile it?

Answer (score 1):

Does your Jar really contain .java files? It looks unusual, because java-files should be compiled to .class files before packing to Jar.

Maybe http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/ can help you.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that the JAR was not packed correctly.  It contains only Java files, no .class files.

Comment: Maybe this can help: http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/project-setup.html#building-compile-on-save

Answer (score 0):

Haven't you seen some warnings while installing the jar?

I have seen that message when I had erroneously the same jar installed twice - as compile library and as a test library.

As the result, many of packages became invisible.

After removing the jar from compile libraries everything become visible.

Answer (score -1):

One can understand, **why** the such a problem may comes from.
I have had this problem, when used in Netbeans IDE the java SOURCE code using 
**pasting** code from the other internet source by Ctrl-C Ctrl-V key combination.
(Pasting from other IDE).
The reserching of prombled showed that the problem is of **absence** of 
statement "package *nameofpackage*" in code, that you want to use as library.

So, to correct the mistake you need to **insert the statement *package*** in project you want to use as library.
Perhaps, you need also to delete and link library in Netbeans again.
To link library I used the the menu point "**Add library as JAR file**" from tree menu item in project "Libraries" and rignt-mouse click - then "add library"